# How can I show the time in the agenda in SfCalendar? The Agenda only shows the subject not the start and end time

Tags: flutter

How to show the start and end time in agenda? Here's the picture of my output for the reference. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfk9t.png. What method do I need to use in order to show the time with the subject in the agenda.
Here's the code in sf calendar.

```
Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        // flex: 2,
        child: Container(
          child: isLoading
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : SfCalendar(
                  view: CalendarView.month,
                  initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
                  dataSource: TaskDataSource(taskContent),
                  monthViewSettings: MonthViewSettings(
                      showAgenda: true,
                      agendaItemHeight: 40,
                      showTrailingAndLeadingDates: false),
                ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Here's the code for the mapping of appointments.

```
    class TaskDataSource extends CalendarDataSource {
  TaskDataSource(List<Task> source) {
    appointments = source;
  }

  @override
  DateTime getStartTime(int index) {
    return appointments![index].dateSched;
  }

  @override
  DateTime getEndTime(int index) {
    return appointments![index].dateSched.add(const Duration(hours: 1));
  }

  @override
  bool isAllDay(int index) {
    return true;
  }

  @override
  String getSubject(int index) {
    return appointments![index].title;
  }

  @override
  Color getColor(int index) {
    return Colors.blue;
  }

  @override
  String getNotes(int index) {
    return appointments![index].description;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does taskContent have inside? Does it have values for the stat time and end time?

Comment: yes it does, found the answer now thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@override
  bool isAllDay(int index) {
    return false;
  }
```

just change the isAllday into false to show the start and end time in the agenda. It works on me